# Iterating through cells to change cell color is too slow

Tags: vba, excel

I want to change all cells in a workbook to white interior if they don't have a color already. I have a working macro (see below), however, it is **extremely slow** and often crashes. If I step through the code manually or it happens not to crash, it works perfectly, but of course very slow.

Can anyone help me find out how to make this perform faster?

Kind regards,
Frank

```
Sub Fill_Cells_White_When_Blank()
    Dim mSheet As Worksheet
    Dim mCell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For Each mSheet In Workbooks("Name.xlsx").Worksheets
        For Each mCell In mSheet.UsedRange
            On Error Resume Next
            If mCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
                mCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            End If

        Next
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Ricardo A: Thank you very much for your edits, I think it made the post easier to understand.

Comment: Apparently (perhaps I missed something), you are changing the colors to every cell in the worksheet, one by one. If you are working with Office 2016, it means that you are changing the colors to 16,384 (columns) X 1048576 (rows) = 17,179,869,184. That should take some time, don't you think?

Comment: By the way, are you aware of the **CONDITIONAL FORMAT** feature of Excel?

Comment: Correction to my first comment: You are changing the color to every cell in every worksheet within the Excel, so 17,179,869,184 X number of worksheets = BIIIIIIIGGGGG NUMBER!!!

Comment: @FDavidov Actually, he's only changing the `UsedRange` on each worksheet.  But still, that could be a large number of cells

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, indeed!!

Comment: @Franksta, please specify what is the SIZE of the range and how many worksheets are there in the workbook.

Comment: @FDavidov, the workbook has a very complicated formatting, therefore, it is cumbersome to make changes manually. We are talking about 30-40 sheets, with usedRanges of about 20 columns and 200 rows each. I could see how the whole workbook takes time. But for each sheet I would think this should go quickly.

Comment: Down Vote_using white to color all cells that are not colored is a waste of time and resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to `Union` the ranges and then change `ColorIndex` in one go like below and see if it works faster.

```
Sub Fill_Cells_White_When_Blank()
    Dim mSheet As Worksheet
    Dim mCell As Range, mCells As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    On Error Resume Next    
    For Each mSheet In Workbooks("Name.xlsx").Worksheets
        Set mCells = Nothing
        For Each mCell In mSheet.UsedRange
            If mCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
                If mCells Is Nothing Then
                    Set mCells = mCell
                Else
                    Set mCells = Union(mCells, mCell)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If Not mCells Is Nothing Then mCells.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Why issue `On Error Resume Next` for every cell tested ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, thank you so much. This is a perfect solution. Somehow setting the attribute for the whole range is much faster. The single cell approach was around 5 min per sheet (if it didn't fail). Your approach is 10 seconds for the whole workbook! (The resume next was in there because strangely I hat errors thrown with #NV cell values)

Comment: @Franksta perhaps it has something to do with cell "interactions" per sheet. Here we are changing it once for n cells and not n times!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Find and Replace dialog box. It allows you to select format to be search and replace to format you need. Try it out.

[image: SO_Find_and_Replace]

Comment: thank you for your advice. I did not use that approach, because my actual problem is bigger. I will have a whole array of colors which needs to be mapped in several workbooks, doing them one by one takes too long. Sorry, I should have added that, I just tried focusing on the issue which I could not solve.

Comment: Well, you can do the same in VBA. Just run macro recorder and do all the actions in GUI. Clean out the generated code and use it in your code. :)